# Using torchtext for inference

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I wonder what is the right way to use `torchtext` for inference.

Let's assume I've trained the model and `dump` all Fields with built vocabularies. It seems the next step is to use [torchtext.data.Example](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#example) to load one single example. Somehow I should numeralize it by using loaded Fields and create an Iterator.

I would appreciate any simple examples of using `torchtext` for inference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a trained model and vocabulary (which is part of the text field , you don't have to save the whole class) :

```py
    def read_vocab(path):
        #read vocabulary pkl 
        import pickle
        pkl_file = open(path, 'rb')
        vocab = pickle.load(pkl_file)
        pkl_file.close()
        return vocab



    def load_model_and_vocab():
        import torch
        import os.path
    
        my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        vocab_path = os.path.join(my_path, vocab_file)
        weights_path = os.path.join(my_path, WEIGHTS)
    
        vocab = read_vocab(vocab_path)
        model = classifier(vocab_size=len(vocab))
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights_path))
        model.eval()
        return model, vocab
    
    
    def predict(model, vocab, sentence):
        tokenized = [w.text.lower() for w in nlp(sentence)]  # tokenize the sentence
        indexed = [vocab.stoi[t] for t in tokenized]         # convert to integer sequence
        length = [len(indexed)]                              # compute no. of words
        tensor = torch.LongTensor(indexed).to('cpu')         # convert to tensor
        tensor = tensor.unsqueeze(1).T                       # reshape in form of batch,no. of words
        length_tensor = torch.LongTensor(length)             # convert to tensor
        prediction = model(tensor, length_tensor)            # prediction
        return round(1-prediction.item())
```

"classifier" is the class I defined for my model.

For saving the vocabulary pkl :

```py
    def save_vocab(vocab):
        import pickle
        output = open('vocab.pkl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(vocab, output)
        output.close()
```

And for saving the model after training you can use :

```py
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'saved_weights.pt')
```

Tell me if it worked for you!