# Save and load vocab and weight for torchtext to do inference

Tags: text, pytorch, lstm, torchtext

I have followed [this example](https://www.kaggle.com/swarnabha/pytorch-text-classification-torchtext-lstm/notebook) to build a text classifier using torchtext.

After finishing training, I've saved vocab and weights, but when I've loaded them again to make an inference with validation data, I got zero for accuracy.

I found a similar question [Using torchtext for inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744998/using-torchtext-for-inference) but it does not solve my problem

```
def save_vocab(vocab):
    import pickle
    output = open('vocab.pkl', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(vocab, output)
    output.close()

save_vocab(TEXT.vocab)    
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'saved_weights.pt')
```

```
def read_vocab(path):
    #read vocabulary pkl 
    import pickle
    pkl_file = open(path, 'rb')
    vocab = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    pkl_file.close()
    return vocab

vocab = read_vocab('vocab.pkl')
TEXT = data.Field(batch_first=True, include_lengths = True)
LABEL = data.LabelField(dtype = torch.float, batch_first=True)

TEXT.vocab = vocab
LABEL.vocab = vocab

pretrained_embeddings = TEXT.vocab.vectors
model.embedding.weight.data.copy_(pretrained_embeddings)
model.embedding.weight.data[PAD_IDX] = torch.zeros(EMBEDDING_DIM)

#load weights
path='saved_weights.pt'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path));
model.eval();

model = model.cuda()
acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator)
```

Thanks.

Comment: There have been huge changes in the torchtext API to make it more standard and interoperable with the rest of the PyTorch ecosystem. Can you share which version you're using? It looks like an older version.

Comment: Thanks. The torch version is 1.10.0a0+ecc3718.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

First, I'd suggest checking your model with a validation data set directly. Rather than saving everything and loading it again, simply use the model you've created and run it on a validation dataset. It's possible your issue has little to do with the saving and reloading.

Also, as erip mentioned in the comment above, there have been significant changes to torchtext. I'd suggest migrating your model to the new version. There is a tutorial to do so [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb). There are fewer tutorials available for the new releases, but the workflow is much more intuitive.

Finally, I'd suggest iterating through your vocabulary and embedding, and printing the items both before saving and after loading. If there is an issue there, it should show up pretty obviously.

Comment: Thanks. The torch version is 1.10.0a0+ecc3718. I did a validation check during training. But I want to train the model then save trained weights with vocabulary to do inference later with new data. I will check the tutorial and update the code. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. When using new data, you may be running into issues with out-of-vocab words.